# bibtex custom tag for certain citation

Tags: bibtex

I have a report where I reference articles and standards. 
Whereas for an article it is totally suitable to have a reference tag corresponding to the author's name, e.g. [Adr89], I would expect the tag for a standard to be more specific about the standard number, e.g. [DIN-13201-1] and [DIN-13201-2] instead of the automatically created tags [DIN04a] and [DIN04b].

Is there a way to set a custom tag name for an entry?

I'm using `alphadin` as bibliography style and the standards are of type `@misc`.

Comment: It seems that alphadin isn't able to create your own label. Maybe you can use `biblatex`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Please make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @JosephWright: Done

Comment: You could modify `alphadin` to have customized labels, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91428/21591).

Answer (score 6):

The bibliography style `alphadin`  doesn't support such a custom tag. In relation to your request you have to modify the file `alphadin.bst`.

Instead of this I recommend the package `biblatex` which is more comfortable.

The following example uses `biblatex`. The label is created by the bib entry `shorthand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{DIN-13201-2,
title="DIN EN 13201-2:2004-04 Straßenbeleuchtung - Teil 2: Gütemerkmale",
subtitle="Deutsche Fassung EN 13201-2:2003",
date="2004-04",
language="Deutsch",
shorthand="DIN-13201-2"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Example cite \cite{DIN-13201-2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The complete example after you have run:

```
pdflatex
biber
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

results in

[image]