# Customize appearence of citation of a specific bibliographic entry when using the alpha bibliography style

Tags: bibtex

I use bibtex with `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`

It works fine. My issue is with the following item.

```
@book{sga1,
       key = {{SGA1}},
     TITLE = {Rev\^etements \'etales et groupe fondamental},
     NOTE = {S{\'e}minaire de G{\'e}om{\'e}trie Alg{\'e}brique du Bois
          Marie 1960--1961 (SGA 1),
          Dirig{\'e} par Alexandre Grothendieck. Augment{\'e} de deux
          expos{\'e}s de M. Raynaud,
          Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 224},
     PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
     ADDRESS = {Berlin},
     YEAR = {1971},
     PAGES = {xxii+447},
 }
```

The tradition is to call this book SGA1. But in the text, it appears as SGA71, which is logical, but ugly. Is there a way to customize this specific item so that it appears as SGA1 in the text, without modifying its year?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Real quick: How do you want the label of this entry to be typeset in the bibliography: as `[SGA1]` (i.e., as in the adjusted citations) or as `[SGA71]` (the default of the `alpha` bibliography style)? Please advise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works. We create a new style, that uses `mylabel` as a label if present, and the default `alpha` label otherwise

1. Find file `alpha.bst` (on my machine it's in directory `<TEXMF>/bibtex/bst/base`) and create a copy named `alpha2.bst` in your working directory.
2. Open the file in any editor.
3. At the beginning, there's a long list named `ENTRY{...}`, add there one more line:

   ```
   mylabel
   ```
4. The find `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` (in my version it's on line 86) and modify it as follows:

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
   { newline$
     "\bibitem[" write$
     mylabel empty$ 'label 'mylabel if$ write$
     "]{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}" write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
   }
   ```
5. Save an close the file.
6. Open your `.bib` file, and add to your entry:

   ```
   mylabel={SGA1},
   ```
7. In your `.tex` file, change your style to `\bibliographystyle{alpha2}`.
8. Run `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`.
9. Happy TeXing!