# Problem with the "Reference" headers

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, sv-classes

I'm writing my thesis with the Springer's package SVmono. The followings are the options for the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap,oribibl]{svmono} 
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha2}
\bibliography{bibliothesis}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

Where the style `alpha2` is a modified version of the style `alpha` and allows to add personal labels to the references. I obtained it thanks to the accepted answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91423/customize-appearence-of-citation-of-a-specific-bibliographic-entry-when-using-th/91428#91428).

---

Now the problem:

The title of the bibliography chapter appears as "References" but the chapter header is "REFERENCES" (with uppercase letters). I'd like to have the headers with lowercase letters.

**note:** The bibliography is longer than a page.

Comment: I get “References” both as the chapter header and in the TOC.

Comment: To be more precise:
In my document only in "the title of the chapter" and in the TOC I have "References". The headers are "REFERENCES"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using neither `caption` nor `tocbibind` with `svmono`. The second is responsible for the uppercasing, by the way.

If you use `natbib`, the references chapter is added to the table of contents; not if that package is not loaded (and you don't want it, if you need an `alpha` style). You're using the `oribibl` option just for this, I think.

Here's a fix:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap,oribibl]{svmono}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\list}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}\list}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

Text for test.

\begin{small}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{SM}
\end{small}

\cleardoublepage

Test to show the page header

\end{document}
```

### Table of contents

[image]

### Pages for the references

[image]